# join data in datatable (laravel)

Tags: ajax, laravel, datatable, controller, yajra-datatable

need to join two data and compile to show in datatable
but i dont know what is wrong in my code

**controller**

```
        $data = DB::table('items')
   ->join('shipments', 'shipments.shp_no','=','items.shp_no_for_it')
   ->select('items.it_arabic_name', 'shipments.shp_destination_shipping_fees')
   ->get();
    return Datatables::of($data)
    ->make(true);
```

**ajax**

```
columns: [

    {data: 'items.it_arabic_name',
      render: function ( data, type, row ) {
        return row.items.it_arabic_name + ' ' + row.shipments.shp_destination_shipping_fees;
   }
    }]
```

get this error

[image: i get this error]

Comment: We dont know too - because you dont show your errors.

Comment: i update error.. thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**solved**

```
columns: [

    {data: 'items.it_arabic_name',
      render: function ( data, type, row ) {
        return row.it_arabic_name + ' ' + row.shp_destination_shipping_fees;
   }
}]
```